# Can you freeze almond paste?

Tags: freezing, almonds

I've got some fresh almonds and they're starting to become stale. I'm thinking of making an almond paste with eggs and sugar.

Does this keep well in the freezer? I suppose it does, but asking doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic Google search hit on numerous sites all which agree that almond paste can be frozen with no deterioration of the product.  The key is to wrap it up in several layers of plastic bags or plastic, then aluminum foil to keep out other flavors from the freezer as my experience has been that ground nuts will absorb odors if improperly wrapped.

Once in the freezer, hopefully in manageable-sized packages for easy thaw and use, the almond paste should keep for several months at least.

I've stored ground almonds in the freezer for a year with no harm to the flavor.

Best of luck!

Comment: What does a layer of aluminium foil achieve? It is never going to be airtight!

Comment: I'd think main drawback of aluminum foil is that it can be punctured quite easily, so you need something else around it to protect it.  Aluminum is somewhat reflective to heat, so it may help when you open the freezer.